# How do I update js file/code on App Launch

Tags: android, ios, react-native, code-push

I want a react-native app, when started on a device to check for some update and download it and use it instead of old js file.
I have checked out Codepush but as an alternative I am searching for a simple and clean implementation for a small case usage.

I just want some js code/file to be updated without bundling the app again or updating it through playstore, maybe suggest some other options too.